# All the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm encountering a ValueError, which states that all input arrays must have the same number of dimensions. The array at index 0 has one dimension, while the array at index 1 has two dimensions.

How can I go about resolving this issue? My intention was to convert a 2D array into a 1D array, but my current approach doesn't seem to be working.

```
#DataFlair - Extract features (mfcc, chroma, mel) from a sound file
def extract_feature(file_name, mfcc, chroma, mel):
    with soundfile.SoundFile(file_name) as sound_file:
        X = sound_file.read(dtype="float32")
        sample_rate=sound_file.samplerate
        if chroma:
            stft=np.abs(librosa.stft(X))
        result=np.array([])
        if mfcc:
            mfccs=np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
            result=np.hstack((result, mfccs))
        if chroma:
            chroma=np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
            result=np.hstack((result, chroma))
        if mel:
            mel=np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=X, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)
            result=np.hstack((result, mel))
        return result
```

```
#DataFlair - Load the data and extract features for each sound file
def load_data(test_size=0.2):
    x,y=[],[]
    for file in glob.glob("D:\\NFT\Data\Ravdess\\Actor_*\\*.wav"):
        file_name=os.path.basename(file)
        emotion=emotions[file_name.split("-")[2]]
        if emotion not in observed_emotions:
            continue
        feature=extract_feature(file, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True)
        x.append(feature)
        y.append(emotion)
    return train_test_split(np.array(x), y, test_size=test_size, random_state=9)
```

```
#DataFlair - Split the dataset
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=load_data(test_size=0.25)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[57], line 2
      1 #DataFlair - Split the dataset
----> 2 x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=load_data(test_size=0.25)

Cell In[56], line 9, in load_data(test_size)
      7 if emotion not in observed_emotions:
      8     continue
----> 9 feature=extract_feature(file, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True)
     10 x.append(feature)
     11 y.append(emotion)

Cell In[54], line 11, in extract_feature(file_name, mfcc, chroma, mel)
      9 if mfcc:
     10     mfccs=np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
---> 11     result=np.hstack((result, mfccs))
     12 if chroma:
     13     chroma=np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=sample_rate).T,axis=0)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py:357, in hstack(tup, dtype, casting)
    355 # As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
    356 if arrs and arrs[0].ndim == 1:
--> 357     return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0, dtype=dtype, casting=casting)
    358 else:
    359     return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1, dtype=dtype, casting=casting)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

Comment: Initialize `result` array with two dimensions `result = np.empty((0, 40)) `  and  ensure that it has the same number of dimensions as `mfccs` (which is 2) `result = np.hstack((result, mfccs.reshape(-1, 40)))`

Comment: What's the purpose of that `hstack`?  Why not just use the result of the `np.mean`, which according the error is already 2d?  When debugging test for shapes at many places; don't guess.